# Virtual box Host only Network Interface

Tags: virtualbox, network-interface

When I am trying to add a new Network Interface for Host only network, Virtual Box version :Version 5.0.22 r108108.

I am getting a following error:

```
Could not find Host Interface Networking driver! Please reinstall.


Result Code: 
E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Component: 
HostNetworkInterfaceWrap
Interface: 
IHostNetworkInterface {455f8c45-44a0-a470-ba20-27890b96dba9}
```

Comment: Check if you still have the "VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter" connection in "Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections". If not, you should create a new network interface pointing to the VirtualBox  network driver.

Comment: @VinsanityL: Yes I have the connection.

Comment: Reinstalling the virtual box helped me.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Reinstall the Virtual Box and restart your system.

Comment: Had exactly same issue, Reinstalling VirtualBox Version 5.1.12 r112440 on Win 10 fixed the issue.
I did not have virtualbox Host-Only Network interface Created already after Reinstalling I got one.

Comment: I guess this issue comes only for Win 10 users. :P

Comment: Repairing the installation didn't help for me. I had to manually uninstall existing VirtualBox first. Not sure if the following was relevant, but I also started the installer with admin privileges.

Comment: I have to log in and give you a vote up, you save my time. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You must reinstall the driver.

Go to device manager, you will find an "unknown driver" missing then update it by pointing to this link:
`C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\drivers\network\netadp6\VBoxNetAdp6.inf`

Comment: This was helpful to me. I went to Device Manager>Action>Add Legacy Hardware. I selected network adapter then browsed to `C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\drivers\network\netadp6\` and picked the driver.

Comment: If the 'add legacy hardware' option isn't there or if the 'unknown device' doesn't appear -- you can always right-click the .inf file and select 'Install'.

Answer (score 2):

open virtual box -> select the default virtual machine-> setting -> network -> change host-only to bridged networking -> start virtual machine -> Open docker quickStart Terminal to connect

Answer (score 1):

Existing answers didn't help me, but [this](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?p=421274&sid=b16c9616e28d50204240ce40bdfbd9c1#p421274) did:

> Open the Network tab of your VirtualBox settings.
>
> Cycle through all Adapter tabs and make sure none of them points to something non-existent, **even if the adapter is disabled**.
>
> For disabled adapters, enable them, set to Not attached, then disable again.
>
> Save.

**UPD**: that didn't solve it. The solution was to reinstall VirtualBox like @ArpitArgarwal suggests, but simply repairing it didn't help. What helped was:

1. Manually uninstall existing VirtualBox.
2. Install VirtualBox, starting the installer with admin privileges.

Comment: In case anyone like me tryed everything to uninstall Virtualbox after a bad update - having vierualbox doing a "rollback" of the installation (green bar going backward) - i'd recommand using the Windows's Program Install Uninstall Troubleshooter  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/fix-problems-that-block-programs-from-being-installed-or-removed-cca7d1b6-65a9-3d98-426b-e9f927e1eb4d  .

Answer (score 1):

Follow the below settings and it will allow you to configure Host-only Adapter-

1. Open VirtualBox Manager
2. Click on "**File**" -> "**Host Network Manager**"

[image]

3. Click on "**Create**".

[image]

4. Now you can select "**Host-only Adapter**" from Network tab of a VM.

[image]

**Note:** Screenshot taken from VirtualBox 6.0

Answer (score 0):

1.Open Virtual Box with Run as administrator. Then it showing below snapshot error: 0x80004005 belongs to Failed to open a session for the virtual machine. Check with this error correct or not.

http://commandstech.com/how-to-resolve-failed-to-open-a-session-for-the-virtual-machine-error-code-0x80004005/

5.Now, the issue may be solved. If an issue is still pending then close it Virtual Box. Then open with Headless start option. It means that Restart the Virtual Box.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, (worked for me) running and getting the latest update of vbox fix the problem. And got the Host Interface Networking driver automatically installed.
The update I run was:
VirtualBox-6.0.14-133895-Win

Answer (score 0):

In my case I just restarted the system and it worked,i don't know how